# problem with initial state in redux toolkit

Tags: javascript, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

When I check state in redux dev tools, I see `reducers: undefined`. I don't know what is wrong with this code.

postsSlice.js

```js
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'

const postsSlice = createSlice({
  initialState: [{ id: '1', title: 'test', desc: 'test2' }],
  name: 'posts',
  reducers: {},
})

export default postsSlice.reducer
```

store.js

```js
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'
import postsReducer from '../features/postsSlice'


export default configureStore({
  reducer: () => ({
    posts: postsReducer,
  }),
})
```

redux dev tool

> ```
> reducer(pin): undefined
> ```

changed repo, node modules

Answer (score 1):

The `reducer` property of the store creation takes an object with key-values that are reducer functions, or it takes a reducer function directly. It ***doesn't*** take a function that returns this object/reducer function.

```js
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import postsReducer from '../features/postsSlice';

export default configureStore({
  reducer: {
    posts: postsReducer,
  },
});
```

or

```js
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import postsReducer from '../features/postsSlice';

export default configureStore({
  reducer: postsReducer,
});
```

Comment: i copied your code, and still i have undefined

Comment: @Rafał I notice your `postsSlice` state slice doesn't actually have any reducer functions, that might be the issue. Can you create a ***running*** [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) demo that reproduces the issue that we could inspect live?

Comment: @Rafał Actually, here's a basic [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/problem-with-initial-state-in-redux-toolkit-pvtfd9) that creates the store with your state slice and I can see the state in the redux dev tools, the initial state is in there. It's correct and working as far as I can tell. Give your page a reload so the store is reloaded.

Answer (score 0):

There might be an issue with how you're configuring the Redux store. In your store.js, you're using a function for the `reducer` field, but it should be an object.

Here's how you can fix the store.js code:

```
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import postsReducer from '../features/postsSlice';

export default configureStore({
  reducer: {
    posts: postsReducer,
  },
});
```

Notice that I've changed the `reducer` field from a function to an object with the `postsReducer` assigned to the `posts` key. This should resolve the issue you're facing with the Redux DevTools showing `reducer: undefined`.

With this change, your Redux store configuration should work correctly and your reducers should be properly connected to the store.

Comment: i copied your code, and still i have undefined